# Intent in MainActivity starting another activity, prevents MainActivity code from executing

Tags: android, kotlin

Im new to kotlin and Im trying to make a navigation bar with a time selector based on NumberPicker, with 2 other empty fragments (for now atleast), but my problem is that if I start an intent the Navigation bar doesnt show, when I dont put it in code (intent) the navigation bar shows up working correctly, what Im doing wrong, am I missing something??

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.helloworld
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.helloworld.databinding.ActivityMainBinding




class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)



        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {

            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.first -> replaceFragment(Home())
                R.id.second -> replaceFragment(Voices())
                R.id.third -> replaceFragment(Settings())

                else -> {
                }
            }
            true
        }


        replaceFragment(Home())

            Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).also {
            startActivity(it)


    }
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

SecondActivity.kt

```
package com.example.helloworld

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_second.*

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)


        numPickerMin2.minValue = 0
        numPickerMin2.maxValue = 23

        numPickerSec2.minValue = 0
        numPickerSec2.maxValue = 59

        var min = 0
        var sec = 0
        var amOrPm = ""


        val str = arrayOf<String>("AM", "PM")
        numPickerAM2.minValue = 0
        numPickerAM2.maxValue = (str.size - 1)
        numPickerAM2.displayedValues = str

        numPickerMin2.setOnValueChangedListener { numberPicker, i, i2 ->
            min = numberPicker.value
        }

        numPickerSec2.setOnValueChangedListener { numberPicker, i, i2 ->
            sec = numberPicker.value
        }

        numPickerAM2.setOnValueChangedListener { numberPicker, i, i2 ->
            val i = numberPicker.value
            amOrPm = str[i]
        }


        btGetValue2.setOnClickListener {
            reminderTime2.text = "$min : $sec : $amOrPm"
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.2">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HelloWorld">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundFirst"
    tools:context=".Home">



    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:text="Choose Alert"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numPickerMin2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/numPickerSec2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/numPickerSec2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/numPickerSec2"
        app:np_dividerColor="@color/black"
        app:np_dividerDistance="55dp"
        app:np_dividerLength="100dp"
        app:np_dividerThickness="3dp"
        app:np_formatter=""
        app:np_height="180dp"
        app:np_max="12"
        app:np_min="0"
        app:np_selectedTextColor="@color/selected"
        app:np_selectedTextSize="60sp"
        app:np_textAlign="textAlignCenter"
        app:np_textColor="@color/black"
        app:np_textSize="40sp"
        app:np_typeface="@string/roboto_light"
        app:np_value="1"
        app:np_wheelItemCount="10"
        app:np_width="74dp"
        app:np_wrapSelectorWheel="true" />

    <com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numPickerSec2"


        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/numPickerAM2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:np_dividerColor="@color/black"
        app:np_dividerDistance="55dp"
        app:np_dividerLength="100dp"
        app:np_dividerThickness="3dp"
        app:np_formatter=""
        app:np_height="180dp"
        app:np_max="59"
        app:np_min="0"
        app:np_selectedTextColor="@color/selected"
        app:np_selectedTextSize="60sp"
        app:np_textAlign="textAlignCenter"
        app:np_textColor="@color/black"
        app:np_textSize="40sp"
        app:np_typeface="@string/roboto_light"
        app:np_value="1"
        app:np_wheelItemCount="10"
        app:np_width="74dp"
        app:np_wrapSelectorWheel="true" />

    <com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numPickerAM2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/numPickerSec2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/numPickerSec2"
        app:np_dividerColor="@color/black"
        app:np_dividerDistance="55dp"
        app:np_dividerLength="100dp"
        app:np_dividerThickness="3dp"
        app:np_formatter=""
        app:np_height="180dp"
        app:np_max="1"
        app:np_min="0"
        app:np_selectedTextColor="@color/selected"
        app:np_selectedTextSize="60sp"
        app:np_textAlign="textAlignCenter"
        app:np_textColor="@color/black"
        app:np_textSize="40sp"
        app:np_typeface="@string/roboto_light"
        app:np_value="1"
        app:np_wheelItemCount="10"
        app:np_width="74dp"
        app:np_wrapSelectorWheel="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btGetValue2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/selected"

        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Get Time"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reminderTime2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reminderTime2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/helloday_logo" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"

        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you really always want to start the second activity as soon as the first activity is created? If so, why even bother with the first activity and just start the second activity directly from the launcher?

Comment: Ive already tried it, the problems stays same, number picker works, navigation bar disappears

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? What should happen when the user starts the app? Please show some screenshots or mocks. I don't think it makes any sense to call `startActivity()` in `onCreate()`. But I need more information to be able to make a suggestion of what to do instead.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mkoTGRl.jpg   when user starts an app, he is gretted by time picker, on the second page, he can see his times, everything driven by nav bar at the bottom

Comment: Why is the time picker on the second page if it is supposed to be shown as soon as the user starts the app? Shouldn't this be on the first page? Or maybe we should talk about pages as "time picker page" and "home page" rather than "first" and "second".

Comment: Should the user see the time picker every time they start the app? Or do they only see it the first time?

Comment: Well, as I said im new to this, and thats how I saw it on tutorial, on Activitymain.xml was just the nav bar and on second page was the rest, I assumed this is the way

Comment: Yup every time, with possibility of returning to it via the nav bar

Comment: Was the tutorial you saw this on using two separate activities or was it using one activity with multiple fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a second activity, I suggest that you create another fragment. Use it in the same way as the other fragments which you currently have in your app.